# how to determine the students in the classroom

Tags: php, arrays

i have data like this 
"

```
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.93307929758057 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => KPR [value] => 0.92840770381433 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => ANM [value] => 0.92789622246959 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.92654448024521 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.92345671574541 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => MM [value] => 0.92227685842375 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => TKR [value] => 0.919028255802 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.91566383908939 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.91503579165701 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.91256006438937 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.91247313037828 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => KPR [value] => 0.90697517431011 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.89855211849553 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => ANM [value] => 0.89575504303048 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => MM [value] => 0.89533409041305 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => MM [value] => 0.89332468578125 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => MM [value] => 0.87550088531854 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => TKR [value] => 0.87197131764132 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.86273862611451 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => ANM [value] => 0.84979744170074 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.846367089011 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => ANM [value] => 0.84604275752245 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => MM [value] => 0.8447277613813 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_307 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.83059013563678 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => ANM [value] => 0.82294948018978 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.82293050617776 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => TKR [value] => 0.81153043758039 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_334 [class] => TKJ [value] => 0.81119925785541 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => TKR [value] => 0.80803732051624 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_334 [class] => RPL [value] => 0.80554682130365 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => KPR [value] => 0.80232985114455 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_093 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.80144125521351 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => KPR [value] => 0.79835079825869 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_251 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.79666213395659 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_334 [class] => MM [value] => 0.78634534742704 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => KPR [value] => 0.78618264230399 )
Array ( [id] => Siswa_294 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.78580110175459 )
```

"

as you can see, each id having 7 grades with different classes.
my question is, how to determine the class id for the id selection condition based on the largest value so that each id only be in one class only..
each class has different limit for id acceptable

Comment: So you want us to write your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would loop the array but first 1 thing.

Change all lines into a real array like this

```
Array ( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.93307929758057 )
```

into

```
$myarray [] = Array( [id] => Siswa_289 [class] => TSM [value] => 0.93307929758057 );
```

You can then use foreach to go to through the Array.

```
foreach($myarray as $k => $data_r){

// Add your if in here for instance
if($data_r["class"]=="TSM){
    print_r($data_r);
}

}
```